# How to create a new column with an incrementing sequence number in an R dataframe, such that it gets incremented based on other column values

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr

This is what my simplified dataframe looks like -

```
App       IsNewSession
Word         TRUE   
Excel        FALSE   
Chrome       TRUE  
Notepad      FALSE  
Chrome       FALSE  
Notepad      FALSE  
Excel        TRUE  
Chrome       FALSE
```

I need to create a new column called SessionNumber. Each time IsNewSession = TRUE, the session number should be the previous row's session number + 1. Otherwise, it just retains the same session number as the previous row.

Desired data frame -

```
App     IsNewSession   SessionNumber
Word     TRUE            1
Excel    FALSE           1
Chrome   TRUE            2
Notepad  FALSE           2
Chrome   FALSE           2 
Notepad  FALSE           2
Excel    TRUE            3
Chrome   FALSE           3
```

I can do this using a for loop but my dataframe is pretty large (250K rows) and it takes a really long time.

I tried using mutate like this, but that doesn't work either.
df$SessionNumber = 1

```
library(dplyr)

df <- df %>% 
  mutate(SessionNumber = ifelse(IsNewSession, lag(SessionNumber) + 1, lag(SessionNumber)))
```

What is a good performant way to do this in R?

Thanks!

Comment: `df$SessionNumber <- cumsum(df$IsNewSession)`

Comment: ....assuming that your variable is logical and not a character variable :-)

Comment: The question in the comment doesn't work if the first value is `FALSE`.

Comment: @troh I thought the first value would always be `TRUE` since the column is `IsNewSession`.

Comment: @www I see your point. I was thinking in a more generalized approach.

Comment: @troh I saw your answer. Nice approach.

Comment: Thanks @www and @troh! This works as expected!

Comment: @Aruna Great. Remember to accept troh's answer if you think it is helpful.

Answer (score 1):

The question in the comment doesn't work if the first value is `FALSE`.

```
df$SessionNumber <- cumsum(df$IsNewSession) + as.numeric(!df$SessionNumber[1])
```